# Docker file build failed

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I try to build my docker file but it has failed.

I have folder structure in vscode like that:-

[image]

In my docker file have only few command:-

```
  COPY requirements.txt /tmp/pip-tmp/
  RUN pip install  -r /tmp/pip-tmp/requirements.txt \
  && rm -rf /tmp/pip-tmp
```

I got an error messege:-

```
PS C:\LearbayDatascience> docker build  -t proj:myapp /.devcontainer
unable to prepare context: path "/.devcontainer" not found
PS C:\LearbayDatascience> docker build  -t proj:myapp C:/LearbayDatascience/.devcontainer
[+] Building 0.6s (7/8)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:0-3.10-bullseye                                                                    0.5s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => [1/4] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:0-3.10-bullseye@sha256:21a12816fcadaa16dabb4ba0e8c358361d02ea062b1b89db8786eb67173489d0              0.0s 
 => CACHED [2/4] RUN if [ "none" != "none" ]; then su vscode -c "umask 0002 && . /usr/local/share/nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install none 2>&1"; fi                        0.0s 
 => ERROR [3/4] COPY requirements.txt  /tmp/pip-tmp/requirements.txt                                                                                              0.0s 
------
 > [3/4] COPY requirements.txt  /tmp/pip-tmp/requirements.txt:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/requirements.txt" not found: not found
```

why `requirments.txt` is not found when I run the command from same folder structure.
If I rebuild with vscode `.devcontainer` is loaded successfully.

Please help in this regards.

Comment: change `COPY requirements.txt /tmp/pip-tmp/` to `COPY requirements.txt /tmp/pip-tmp/requirements.txt`

Comment: still I got an error:-(learnbayvenv) PS C:\LearbayDatascience> docker build  -t proj:myapp C:/LearbayDatascience/.devcontainer
[+] Building 0.4s (7/8)
 
 => ERROR [3/4] COPY requirements.txt /tmp/pip-tmp/requirements.txt                                                                                               0.0s 
------
 > [3/4] COPY requirements.txt /tmp/pip-tmp/requirements.txt:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/requirements.txt" not found: not found

Comment: You should search for information about docker build context, then issue will be obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the `dockerfile` in the same dir as the `requirements.txt`

Then in your Dockerfile

```
COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/pip-tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install  -r /tmp/pip-tmp/requirements.txt \
&& rm -rf /tmp/pip-tmp
```

After this navigate to the folder where Dockerfile is located and pass as the build command

```
docker build -t proj:myapp .
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.We need to move requirements.txt to .devcontainer